# How to create Google spreadsheet with Sheet API4 correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-colaboratory

I created a spreadsheet with Sheet APIv4. When I list the directory with Drive APIv3 it shows  []  only. My codes come from the official (Google) sites. I use Python3.6 and Google Colaboratory.

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
sheet_service = build('sheets', 'v4')
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')
```

Creation:

```
spreadsheet_metadata = {'properties': {'title': 'Second spreadsheet2'},
                    'sheets': [
                    {
                        'properties': {
                            'title': 'First Sheet',
                            'gridProperties' : {
                                'columnCount': 6,
                                'rowCount': 11,
                                'frozenRowCount': 1
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                       'properties': {
                           'title': 'Second Sheet',
                           'gridProperties': {
                               'columnCount': 4,
                               'rowCount': 8,
                               'frozenColumnCount': 2
                           }
                       }
                    }
                   ]
                   }
spreadsheet = sheet_service.spreadsheets().create(body=spreadsheet_metadata).execute()
spreadsheet_id = spreadsheet['spreadsheetId']
print('Created "%s"' % spreadsheet['properties']['title'])
print('Spreadsheet ID: {0}'.format(spreadsheet.get('spreadsheetId')))
```

It results in

```
Created "Second spreadsheet2"
Spreadsheet ID: 1fqreW1y3fcdaJmQWS1j25OMKaFjf90XfO38WB4ZIqIM
```

Listing:

```
page_token = None
while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'",
                                          spaces='drive',
                                          fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                          pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        # Process change
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

It results in:

```
[]
```

Since the listing works well (I tested many times), I think the problem is the not-correct `spreadsheet_metadata`. Something is missing, but I have no idea what. I hope someone has more practice. Thanks.

**Update** Thanks to the comment of @Tanaike I discovered my misunderstanding. 
Google strictly makes difference between Excel xlsx files and Google "xlsx" files. So if someone want to handle they together one solution would be to use

```
" mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' or  
 mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'"
```

in the query, but I don't know whether it causes other problems later. Since I have only a few files, maybe I will convert Excel xlsx to Google "xlsx" format considering only one type of files, which is simpler (for me).

Comment: ``application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`` is the mimeType of xlsx file. If you want to retrieve Spreadsheet, how about using ``application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`` to the search query? I'm not sure whether this is what you want. So I asked it as a comment.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. Yes. "Almost" yes. Please give it as an answer, I would like to accept it. After you do this, I will update my question because now I understand the reasons. 
I think this is a bug-like behaviour of Google Drive API v3. Do you think it should be report? I know a workaround for this problem, I will write it in the updated question. Please read it, if you have any idea, question to it, comment it. I want other user to find a useful and correct information.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you update your question? I would like to confirm about "bug-like behaviour of Google Drive API v3" and think of it. And I would like to post an answer and comment by summarizing them.

Comment: @Tanaike Updated. Maybe, instead of "bug-like" would be better to say "not so user friendly". But remembering for this, everything works well.

Comment: Thank you for updating it. I think that your additional query is suitable as the method for retrieving both Excel files and Google Spreadsheet files. If the number of files became large, for example, how about separating API call for each mimeType? By the way, please post it as an answer and accept it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.